# How can I get IWpfTextView for EnvDte.ActiveDocument?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I am trying to manipulate the Visual Studio Text Editor scrollbar values. The problem is that I have only the dte.ActiveDocument and it is not possible to do it from there.

My extension is loaded only once when VS starts and I capture dte.Events.CommandEvents. At some point I want to change the scrollbar values for the ActiveDocument. To do this I need IWpfTextView or ITextView. Do you have any idea how can I get an instance of that object?

```
internal class MyExtension
    {
        private CommandEvents commandEvents;

        private DTE dte;

        public MyExtension(DTE dte)
        {
            this.dte = dte;
            commandEvents = dte.Events.CommandEvents;
            commandEvents.BeforeExecute += commandEvents_BeforeExecute;
        }

        void commandEvents_BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var doc = dte.ActiveDocument
            // CHANGE SCROLLBAR VALUES HERE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this. In the main class of the extension I get SVsTextManager

```
public sealed class MyExtensionPackage : Package
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        DTE dte = (DTE)base.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        var txtMgr = (IVsTextManager)base.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
        plugin = new MyExtension(dte, txtMgr);
        base.Initialize();
    }
}

internal class MyExtension
    {
        private CommandEvents commandEvents;

        private DTE dte;
        private IVsTextManager txtMngr;

        public MyExtension(DTE dte, IVsTextManager txtMngr)
        {
            this.txtMngr = txtMngr;
            this.dte = dte;
            commandEvents = dte.Events.CommandEvents;
            commandEvents.BeforeExecute += commandEvents_BeforeExecute;
        }

        void commandEvents_BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var doc = dte.ActiveDocument

            IVsTextView textViewCurrent;
            txtMngr.GetActiveView(1, null, out textViewCurrent);
            int a, b, c, verticalScrollPosition;

            var scrollInfo = textViewCurrent.GetScrollInfo(1, out a, out b, out c, out verticalScrollPosition);
            textViewCurrent.SetScrollPosition(1, verticalScrollPosition);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about IWpfTextView which I am going to need?

Comment: It was long time ago... I do not remember well what is going on here. I would try to resolve WpfTextView as a service similar to the base.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager))